# "​Compare archives"​ menu item missing in "Git History" view?

Tags: intellij-idea

In IntelliJ IDEA, in Project view, when I select 2 *.jar files then I can execute "​Compare archives" menu item.

But when I select 2 revisions of the *.jar file in "Git history" view then "​Compare archives" menu item is not available (only "Compare" menu item is available).

Is there a trick to get "​Compare archives" in "Git history" view?

Answer (score 1):

Just invoke Diff with a shortcut (`Ctrl/Cmd+D`) while 2 revisions selected in the History

Comment: You are right. I have updated my IDEA to 2017.2.5 version and now I can see it works fine (as you described)! Thank you for your answer.